# Find $f\circ f$ if $f(t)=\dfrac{t}{(1+t^2)^{1/2}},\ \ t\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find $f\circ f$ if $f(t)=\dfrac{t}{(1+t^2)^{1/2}},\ \ t\in \mathbb{R}$

$  a.)\ \dfrac{1}{(1+2t^2)^{1/2}} \\
\color{green}{ b.)\ \dfrac{t}{(1+2t^2)^{1/2}}}\\~\\
 c.)\ (1+2t^2)\\~\\
 d.)\ \text{none of these} \\$

I tried to put the value $t=1$ and after checking concluded that it's $d.)$ but the book is giving option $b.)$.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to 12th grade.

Comment: $f(1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ so $f \circ f (1) =f( \frac{1}{\sqrt 2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ which matches both a) and b)

Comment: f(0) = 0 eliminates a) and c). This doesn't prove that b) is correct, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our formula for $f$ is
$$f(\Box)=\frac{\Box}{\sqrt{1+\Box^2}}$$

With this in mind we have
\begin{align*}
f\bigl(f(t)\bigr)
&=f\left(\fbox{$f(t)$}\right) \\
&=\frac{\fbox{$f(t)$}}{\sqrt{1+\fbox{$f(t)$}^2}} \\
&=\frac{\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)^2}} \\
&=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}}\cdot\sqrt{1+t^2}} \\
&=\frac{t}{\sqrt{\left(1+t^2\right)+\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\cdot\left(1+t^2\right)}} \\
&=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2+t^2}} \\
&= \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+2\,t^2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: +1 for the $\square$'s. I have always loved this notation to prove things like this.

Answer (score 5):

$$ f(f(t))=\frac { \frac {t}{\sqrt {1+t^{ 2 }}  }  }{ \sqrt { 1+\frac { t^{ 2 } }{ 1+t^{ 2 } }  }  } =\frac { t }{ \sqrt { 1+2t^{ 2 } }  }$$